# Getting only Album titles, playlists in MPMediaPickerController

Tags: iphone, audio, mpmediapickercontroller

I am trying to figure out how to get the MPMediaPickerController to display only albums and playlists.  I can get the lists via the MPMediaQuery, but don't know how to feed that to the picker, or get the picker to use the query, or....

Any help would be greatly appreciated (or a solid whack on the head if this is a stupid question and it can't be done).

:bp:

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the documentation, `MPMediaPickerController` is not configurable in that way. You would have to build your own interface from scratch (i.e. get the items you want with `MPMediaQuery` and feed the results to a custom UITabBarController/UINavigationController/UITableView interface.